# Umbraco 7 - Alternative URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7 and I need to achieve something which I am not entirely sure of the best way to approach it.

Basically I have vacancies on a website that have URLs currently such as this:

/vacancies/a/almighty-school/live/first-year-teacher/

What I want is for the URL to NOT show the /a and /live part (which are needed for structuring in the administration area), so basically the above URL would be:

/vacancies/almighty-school/first-year-teacher

I am not entirely sure of the best way of doing this, I know about URL Rewriting but am not sure if that could do this and if it could I really am not that clued up on the regular expressions needed to create it.

Any ideas anyone??

Answer (score 7):

Add a property called umbracoUrlAlias, type Textstring, to your document type. Set the value to be "/vacancies/almighty-school/first-year-teacher".

This is a "magic string" that will then allow the document to be accessed via an alternate URL.

You could also set up a ContentService.Saving event to automatically set the value of this on the given node according to some preset rules.

Comment: Is the umbracoUrlAlias property still supported in Umbraco 7.1.4 as I have just tried what you said above and this does not seem to work.

Comment: Apologies, it does work, I didn't realise you shouldn't put a / on the end of the alternate url

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to tackle this is to create your own Segment Provider:

> When the URL is build up, umbraco will convert every node into a segment. Each published Content has a url segment.

The documentation for manipulating these segments can be found here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Request-Pipeline/outbound-pipeline

Comment: Where would the class for this be placed? I have created a test class file based on the example in the URL you sent and placed it into the App_Code folder but it does not appear to be working??

Comment: @user3811724 It might need to be properly compiled in a dll, Umbraco looks for these classes on app pool startup, dynamically compiled App_Code might be a bit too late. And if you do have a compiled class you can of course set breakpoints to see what is going on, so you'll know why it's not working.

Comment: thanks for the additional comments. I have created a compiled class and linked into my Umbraco solution however upon debug the code in the compiled class is never hit, the code is the same as the example you gave and compiles with no errors, am I missing something else, the umbraco version is 7.1.4

Comment: @user3811724 Looks like you need to insert the provider during startup and then publish the documents for which you want the URLs to be different (I personally have never tried this so that's why I don't know exactly). This could help: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/49059-Custom-IUrlSegmentProvider-not-hit